# Flutter put 3 different counter classes all in 1 counter

Tags: flutter, dart, counter

I have made 3 different classes for 3 different containers. all of these contain a button to add points. i want to have 1 counter that counts all of these points but i cant figure out how.

main.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'input_page.dart';

void main() => runApp(BasketballCounter());

class BasketballCounter extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Color(0xFFEE682D),
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Color(0xFFEE682D),
      ),
      home: InputPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

this is my CardDesign.dart:

```
class CardDesign3 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CardDesign3State createState() => _CardDesign3State();
}
class _CardDesign3State extends State<CardDesign3> {
  int counter3 = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            counter3 += 3 ;
            print(counter3);
          });
        },
        child: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Color(0xFFEF7F4D),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          ),
          child: Text(
            'Vanaf de 3 punter lijn!',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: 'Bullpen3D',
              fontSize: 20,
            ),
          ),
          height: 100,
          width: 100,
        ));
  }
}

class CardDesign2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CardDesign2State createState() => _CardDesign2State();
}

class _CardDesign2State extends State<CardDesign2> {
  int counter2 = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            counter2 += 2;
            print(counter2);
          });
        },
        child: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Color(0xFFEF7F4D),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          ),
          child: Text(
            'Vanaf de 2 punter lijn',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: 'Bullpen3D',
              fontSize: 20,
            ),
          ),
          height: 100,
          width: 100,
        ));
  }
}

class CardDesign1 extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _CardDesign1State createState() => _CardDesign1State();
}

class _CardDesign1State extends State<CardDesign1> {
  int counter1 = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            counter1++;
            print(counter1);
          });
        },
        child: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Color(0xFFEF7F4D),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          ),
          child: Text(
            'Vanaf de 1 punter lijn',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: 'Bullpen3D',
              fontSize: 20,
            ),
          ),
          height: 100,
          width: 100,
        ));
  }
}

class HoopDesign extends StatelessWidget {
  const HoopDesign({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 100.0,
      width: 100.0,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
          image: AssetImage('images/basketballhoop.jpg'),
        ),
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and my inputpage that shows all the containers:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'Container_designs.dart';

class InputPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _InputPageState createState() => _InputPageState();
}

class _InputPageState extends State<InputPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('basketball counter'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Row(children: <Widget>[Expanded(child: HoopDesign())]),
          ),
          Expanded(
              child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: CardDesign1(),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: CardDesign3(),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: CardDesign2(),
              ),
            ],
          )),
          Expanded(
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: CardDesign1(),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: CardDesign3(),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: CardDesign2(),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: HoopDesign(),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

im sorry if the code is shit. Im a student in my 2nd year and still learning :)

Answer (score 0):

I made some modifications to your code. These modifications include removing duplication classes.

```
class InputPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _InputPageState createState() => _InputPageState();
}

class _InputPageState extends State<InputPage> {
  int counter = 0;

  void incrementalCounter({int? count}) {
    setState(() {
      counter = counter + count!;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('basketball counter'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Row(children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                  child: HoopDesign(
                countDisplay: counter,
              ))
            ]),
          ),
          Expanded(
              child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: CardDesign(
                  label: 'Vanaf de 1 punter lijn',
                  onTap: () => incrementalCounter(count: 1),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: CardDesign(
                  label: 'Vanaf de 3 punter lijn',
                  onTap: () => incrementalCounter(count: 3),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: CardDesign(
                  label: 'Vanaf de 2 punter lijn',
                  onTap: () => incrementalCounter(count: 2),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )),
          Expanded(
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: CardDesign(
                      onTap: () => incrementalCounter(count: 1),
                      label: 'Vanaf de 1 punter lijn'),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: CardDesign(
                      label: 'Vanaf de 3 punter lijn',
                      onTap: () => incrementalCounter(count: 3)),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: CardDesign(
                      label: 'Vanaf de 2 punter lijn',
                      onTap: () => incrementalCounter(count: 2)),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: HoopDesign(
                    countDisplay: counter,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
    
    
    class CardDesign extends StatelessWidget {
      final Function onTap;
      final String label;
    
      const CardDesign({Key? key, required this.onTap, required this.label})
          : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              // for card 1 it would be one, for 2 it would be 2 and for 3 it would be 3
              onTap(1);
            },
            child: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Color(0xFFEF7F4D),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              ),
              child: Text(
                label,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Bullpen3D',
                  fontSize: 20,
                ),
              ),
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
            ));
      }
    }
    
    class HoopDesign extends StatelessWidget {
      final int countDisplay;
    
      const HoopDesign({Key? key, required this.countDisplay}) : super(key: key);
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          height: 100.0,
          width: 100.0,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage('images/basketballhoop.jpg'),
            ),
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: I would create a `void` that contains the `setstate` with an `integer` param with how much to increment. so you do not have to put in `setState` 6 times.

Comment: Thank you for your help :). this didnt work since im on a non nullable version of flutter and i almost screwed everything up to make this work lol

Comment: You can just remove the ! and ? symbols from the code. That’s all.